# Loop through a Array of Doubles in a class and set the values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

When I create a class and use the `Sub New()` option, I want to loop through 16 1d and 2d array of doubles and set all elements to 999999999. I have the following code below, but the compiler doesn't like it. Can anybody help me?

```
For Each p As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
    If p.CanRead AndAlso p.PropertyType.Name.IndexOf("Double[]") > -1 Then
        For x As Integer = 0 To DirectCast(p.GetValue(Me, Nothing), Double()).GetLength - 1
            'code to set array element = 999999999
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the dimension when using GetLength on an array that may have multiple dimensions.

Change:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To DirectCast(p.GetValue(Me, Nothing), Double()).GetLength - 1
```

to

```
For x As Integer = 0 To DirectCast(p.GetValue(Me, Nothing), Double()).GetLength(0) - 1
```

It will not compile, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Your suggestion got me far enough to get it working with 1d and 2d arrays. I'll post what I did in case others want to use it.